Get post text of users in facebook group
I have a question.
I am owner of one group in facebook.
I need to get all messages of users in this group.
I want to know how i can to get this access and if it possible to do via FB API ?
Important ! Get Text/Messages not of admin of the group but of the users

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/feed#readperms lists the requirements for accessing a group feed's posts.

I am right ? I can to get access only who created post via APP ? And i don't have any access to users who created post via normal mode (browsers/mobile) ?

No, how the post was created, is irrelevant.

So app + token + permission : after I can for example create a php script and via API get users post body messages right ?
